# Agotime with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a post where I need the Time posted within my success function. My original link looks like this for php.

```
echo "<br/><a href='#' class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>".Agotime($streamitem_data['streamitem_timestamp'])."</a>";
```

And I'm building up my ajax and in my success function I need the Agotime also adding, but I don't know how to go about it, I've got the timestamp just need the function Agotime to do its stuff.

AJAX

```
  <br/><a class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>"+response['streamitem_timestamp']+"</a>
```

My Agotime is a function

```
 function Agotime($date)
{
    if(empty($date)) {
        return "No date provided";
    }

    $periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    $now             = time();
    $unix_date       = strtotime($date);

       // check validity of date
    if(empty($unix_date)) {    
        return "Bad date";
    }

    // is it future date or past date
    if($now > $unix_date) {    
        $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense         = "ago";

    } else {
        $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense         = "from now";
    }

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    if($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }

    return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}
?>
```

Comment: I would like to add Agotime to the link in front of the response if possible. But I don't know how to do so as everything I've tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I added the Agotime into my insert page for when my Ajax makes its call. Works a charm.

```
$json = array();
$check = "SELECT streamitem_id, streamitem_timestamp FROM streamdata";
$check1 = mysql_query($check);
$resultArr = mysql_fetch_array($check1);
$json['streamitem_id'] = $resultArr['streamitem_id'];
$json['streamitem_timestamp'] = Agotime($resultArr['streamitem_timestamp']);
```